# Javascript keydown function is only being called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For some reason when I call this function it only works on the first keydown. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
       var x = 10; 
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

       if(code == 40){

          function rise(x){
          $('#div2').css('bottom',x+'%');
      }

       rise(x);
   x++;
       }
```

Comment: As you don't close your code or even properly indent, I'm a little unsure of the exact code.

Comment: I was having trouble typing into here. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see it working because you reinitialize `x` to `10` every time.

A solution is to put x in the external scope :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 10; 
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
       var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
       function rise(x){
           $('#div2').css('bottom',x+'%');
       }
       rise(x);
       x++;
    });
});
```

Note that there's no reason to define a `rise` function here. You could simply do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 10; 
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
       var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
       $('#div2').css('bottom',x+'%');
       x++;
    });
});
```

(I hope there's a reason for the `code` part).